# __ior__ on custom object returning None ... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class BitSet:

    def __init__(self, n=0):
        self.n = n

    def __ior__(self, other):
        self.n |= other

    def __ror__(self, other):
        return other |= self.n


a = BitSet(1 << 3)
b = BitSet(1 << 4)
a |= b
print(a)
```

Produces `None`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @LevLevitsky: might as well make it an answer, no?  @MikeRand: are you sure that's your code?  Isn't `return other |= self.n` a syntax error?

Comment: @DSM yep, will do. For a moment I thought I was wrong, but yeah, that was the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs:](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) on `__ior__` and other methods:

> These methods are called to implement the augmented arithmetic assignments (+=, -=, *=, /=, //=, %=, **=, <<=, >>=, &=, ^=, |=). These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self).

So your method should `return self`:

```
def __ior__(self, other):
    self.n |= other
    return self
```